# Kattis keeps giving me a Runtime Error on heliocentric

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime-error

Kattis gives me a Runtime Error for [heliocentric](https://open.kattis.com/problems/heliocentric) upon submission. I changed parts of the code and asked my friends and we all have no idea what is wrong. Does anyone have an idea as to what I am missing?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class heliocentric {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int inE;
    int inM;
    boolean collin;
    int days;

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      days = 0;
      collin = false;
      inE = scan.nextInt();
      inM = scan.nextInt();
      if (inE < 0 || inM < 0) {
        collin = true;
      }

      while (collin != true) {
        if (inE == 0 && inM == 0) {
          break;
        }
        inE++;
        if (inE == 365) {
          inE = 0;
        }
        inM++;
        if (inM == 687) {
          inM = 0;
        }
        days++;
        if (inE == 0 && inM == 0) {
          collin = true;
        }
      }
      System.out.println("Case " + i + ": " + days);
    }
    scan.close();
  }
}
```

Input

```
0 0
364 686
360 682
0 1
1 0
```

Output

```
Case 1: 0
Case 2: 1
Case 3: 5
Case 4: 239075
Case 5: 11679
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest you set up a local development environment, which will provide a *lot* more information than just "Runtime Error". (I'd also recommend using more conventional formatting and naming, for the sake of readability.)

Comment: can you post the link to the challenge?

Comment: Ahh yes sorry i thought i did that. https://open.kattis.com/problems/heliocentric

Comment: The code was orinaly written at my PC in VS Code. I just copy pasted it into the webiste.

Comment: have you tried run it in VSCode? what is the runtime? i see the maximum runtime for the task is 1 second. and does it say at which Case you get runtime error?

Comment: Hi i tried in VSCode there i get no errors at all. And the Website does not specify which runtime it is so i am totaly clueless.

Comment: Do you think VSCode spent more than 1 second solving the challenge?

Comment: i dont think so,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is OK, but your I/O isn't, which is often the problem with Kattis submissions.

The description says "at most 10" but the first test case only has 5 lines of input, so your code will probably throw a `java.util.InputMismatchException`.

You can use the following pattern to exit cleanly:

```java
var scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    // read the ints
}

scanner.close();
```

...or slap a `try`/`catch` around your code. That's ugly, but works as a quick way to test a hypothesis.

As an aside, variables with names like `collin` are confusing. This variable isn't necessary; just `break` as soon as you're done with the loop instead of adding more state to have to manage.

There's no need to forward-declare variables. Declare them where you use them, as tightly scoped as possible. This reduces the mental burden it takes to understand the code.

Cleaner:

```java
public class heliocentric {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 1; scanner.hasNextInt(); i++) {
            int days = 0;
            int e = scanner.nextInt();
            int m = scanner.nextInt();

            while (e != 0 || m != 0) {
                e = (e + 1) % 365;
                m = (m + 1) % 687;
                days++;
            }

            System.out.println("Case " + i + ": " + days);
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

There's probably a better mathematical solution to this problem...